# How do I put values calculated in column into another dataframe using name key?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-colaboratory

Quick background check: I am working on a uni project due friday and am working on three datasets about mountain expeditions. One is named `peaks` and contains information about the mountain peaks. Another is named `expeditions` and gives info on the various trips that took place on those peaks.
They both have in common the column `peak_name` (str).
In `expeditions`, I calculated the success rate of each peak like this:

```
exped_peak=expeditions.groupby('peak_name').mean()

peak_success=exped_peak['success']
peak_success
```

`Success` is a column filled with booleans and shows if the expedition succeeded or failed.
THe output is this:[image]

I want to create a column in `peaks` that gives the success rate for each peak.
I did this: `peaks['success_rate']=peaks_success` , but my new column is filled with NaN values. How can I make it right?

I figure it probably has to do with the column 'peak_name' but I have never linked two dataframes like that so it's a bit confusing for me.
Could anyone tell me how to make it work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked does there is data for each one of the peaks in the expeditions file?

Comment: Yes, all data has been cleaned before hand

Comment: I'm asking does peaks Amotsand and Yansa Tsenji exists in both tables? as these 2 are the ones for which you are missing some data.

Comment: Amotsand and Yansa Tsenji both have 0 as values because it looks like they have a 0% success rate. But even for peaks with a higher number, it becomes NaN when I try to put it in the column from the other dataframe

Comment: My logical guess would be to say all the names are in both columns, or at least I hope so. I don't know how to check that either lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) the peak_success dataframe with the peaks dataframe based on the "peak_name" column and assign it back to the peaks dataframe.

```
peaks = peaks.merge(peak_success, how='left', on='peak_name')
```

This is similar to a left join in SQL where the merge() looks at the "peak_name" column in each dataframe and properly align the "success_rate" column into the peaks dataframe based on the matching values.